# Html file with basic Javascript run internally won't load on ipad

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad

I have a simple javascript application that spins a wheel based on drag velocity. It currently works fine in browser despite some bugs. I started testing it on my I-pad and the javascript doesn't load at all. I'm assuming it encounters an internal error. I looked through it and ran an alert at the end of the program uncommenting each line sequentially, there are hang ups in the innerHtml modifications under the drawFrame function. I'm wondering what I'm missing here, I've read the syntax is supported in ipad but it baffles me why this won't run on. code is attached in a paste-bin for reference. https://pastebin.com/H19b0sN5. Below is an example of code that would break the display.

```
var drawFrame = function(){
          if(isDragging){

            var mouseAngle = getMouseAngle()

            var delta = getAngleDelta(lastFrameMouseAngle, mouseAngle);

            currentWheelAngle += delta;
            lastFrameMouseAngle = mouseAngle

            angleHistoryQueue.push(currentWheelAngle)
            if (angleHistoryQueue.length > velocityAverageSpan){
              angleHistoryQueue.shift()
            }
          }
          else{
            currentWheelAngle += angularVelocity
            if( angularVelocity != 0){
              var direction = angularVelocity / Math.abs(angularVelocity);
              angularVelocity = direction * Math.max(Math.abs(angularVelocity) - deceleration, 0)
            }
          }
          head.innerHTML = `<h1>${currentWheelAngle}</h1>`
          wheelImage.style.transform = `rotate(${currentWheelAngle}deg)`
        }
```

Comment: there's a lot of code there which I don't have time to go over in detail, but it appears it's all based on mouse events - `mousemove`, `mousedown` and so on. If the device doesn't have a mouse (like, for example, an iPad), then I don't see why you'd expect it to work...

Comment: I've tested the mouse events, the javascript doesn't break on ipad with them running, & the issue I'm having is that the entire script breaks, the image injected doesn't load, etc. So yeah the Ipad doesn't have a mouse but the code should still run.

Comment: Oh I see now where you set about something going wrong in the `drawFrame` function.I notice you're using "template literals" in there, which I just checked are supported from iOS 9.2 onwards: https://caniuse.com/#feat=template-literals. Not sure what version you've got, if the iPad is a few years old it could be a syntax error because template literals aren't supported?

Comment: I will definitely look into this come monday, than you so much Robin.

Answer (score 0):

This was a template literals es6 compatibility issue as Robin Zigmond advised me to look into.